# Determinant of pullback of metric tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, determinant, tensors, pullback

Consider a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with $\dim M=n$.

Let $\Sigma$ be an embedded submanifold with $\dim\Sigma=k$ and inclusion map $\iota:\Sigma\rightarrow M$. We then define  the induced metric tensor as
$\gamma=\iota^\ast g$ i.e. the pullback of the metric tensor of $M$. Given local coordinates $(x^1,...,x^n)$ for $M$ and $(y^1, ...,y^k)$ for $\Sigma$,
$$\gamma_{ij}=(\iota^\ast g)_{ij}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^i}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^j}g_{\mu\nu} \qquad i,j\in \{1,...n-1\}\quad \mu,\nu\in \{1,...n\}.\tag{1}$$
Where $x^\mu(y)$ parametrizes the submanifold.

Now, I want to relate $\det g$, the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix, and $\det \gamma$, the determinant of a $k\times k$ matrix but looking at $(1)$ I don't know how to proceed. In fact, written in matrix form, that is a product of non square matrices. Is there some other - maybe smarter - way to express $\det{g}$ in terms of $\det\gamma$? The only thing I can expect is that the relation is dependent on our choice of coordinates as a consequence of $(1)$

It would be ok if someone had an idea just for the $k=n-1$ case (i.e. for hypersurfaces case).

Comment: You probably know that given an $n$-by-$n$ matrix, there is no way to write its determinant in terms of any $(n-1)$-by-$(n-1)$ submatrix or vice versa. You can see this even if the matrices are diagonal. Perhaps you could say more about why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Originally I was trying to prove that given the Riemannian volume form, that locally is of the form $\nu_g=\sqrt{\det g}dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^n$, the induced volume form on a hypersurface $\iota^\ast(i_N\nu_g)$ and I wanted to show that this is actually the Riemannian volume form on the hypersurface $\sqrt{\det\gamma}dy^1\wedge...\wedge dy^{n-1}$, $N$ being the unit normal vector. So I needed a way to make $\det\gamma$ appear...

Comment: Eventually my original problem was solved discussing in the chat and using the definition of Riemannian volume form and normal vector, from which what I wanted follows naturally... On the other hand I still wanted to see if I can also manage to show this by brute force calculation.

Comment: Indeed, this is messy with respect to coordinates. It's less messy if you use an adapted orthonormal frame of tangent vectors and its dual frame of cotangent vectors.